# Adding \n at every # characters in string Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to start a new line after every 66 characters for any file that is input into a Ruby script.

```
some_string.insert( 66, "\n" )

puts some_string
```

shows that a new line starts after the 66th character but I need it to happen after *each* 66th character.  In other words, each line should be 66 characters long (except possibly the last).

I'm sure it involves a regex but I've tried various with `insert`, `scan`, `gsub` and cannot get it to work.

I'm new to Ruby and programming and this is the first thing I've tried outside of a tutorial. Thanks for the information, all.

Comment: Why not then putting in position `65`...?

Comment: Surely there's a string wrap method that would be eaiser than `.gsub`

Comment: ...or maybe not. Surprised not to find one...

Comment: *for any file that is input into a Ruby script.* Can you explain what that means or give an example?

Comment: "shows that a new line starts after the 66th character but I need it to happen after every 66th character."  Is there a typo here?  It seems to be saying "it does A but it needs to do A"

Comment: @7stud I put the script in a comment to NNnn I didn't see how to format it correctly. Basically using File.open to get string received from gets.chomp

Comment: @WayneConrad It needs to happen after every 66 characters in the file. Making all of the lines in the file 66 characters long except for possibly the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<your_string>.scan(/.{1,66}/).join("\n")
```

It will basically split `<your_string>` at every 66th character and then re-join it by adding the `\n` between each part.

Or this variation to not split words in half:

```
<your_string>.scan(/.{1,66} /).join("\n")
```

Comment: I've tried something like this before but when I use puts to view the string there is no line break also when written to a file there are only the original line breaks from the paragraphs.

Comment: puts "What file do you want to cut-up?" 
input = gets.chomp 
gysin = File.open(input, "r"){ |file| file.read }
gysin.scan(/.{1,66}/).join('\n')
File.open("out.txt", 'w') {|f| f.write( gysin ) }`

Comment: Because you need to assign the result of the `join()` to a new variable and then work on it. In your case, you should use something like `new_gysin = gysin.scan(/.{1,66}/).join('\n')` and then work on `new_gysin`.

Comment: Thanks, I had to put the \n in double quotes "\n" instead of '\n' but making a new variable was the key

Answer (score 2):

```
some_string.gsub(/.{66}/, "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in exploring an answer that doesn't use RegEx, try something like:

```
a = "Your string goes here"
d = 66
Array(0..a.length/d).collect {|j| a[j*d..(j+1)*d-1]}.join("\n")
```

The RegEx is likely faster, but this uses the Array Constructor, .collect and .join so it might be an interesting learning exercise.  The first part generates an array of numbers based on the number of chunks (`a.length/d`).  The `collect` gathers the substrings in to an array.  The body of the collect generates substrings by ranges on the original string, and the `join` puts it back together with '\n' separators.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to split the string into an array of strings of length 66 and join those strings with a newline character.

```
some_string.scan(/.{1,66}/).join("\n")
```

Comment: Can someone explain why my answer was downvoted? I'd like to avoid this solution if there's a reason why, but my understanding is that this solution works.

Comment: Your solution does work, we actually posted the same :/

Comment: Shouldn’t there be "\n" in double-quotes? This way you are adding literal backslash + n every 66 characters, instead of an actual new-line.

Comment: This doesn’t work as expected. It drops the last line if it is not exactly 66 characters long. Use `/.{1,66}/` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Glutexo, I've made those changes